# How to show data by object's type in RecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of items with types [a,b,c,d] indicates status of item. When I click on ButtonA I want to show items with types [a,b] in recyclerview, and click on ButtonB show items with types [c,d]. My current solutions is using two list and two adapter, I wonder if there's better approach, thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its really Easy! I guess in your object model u have Boolean field. You can use Filterable interface.
Just implement it in activity/fragment or viewModel to filter list that u r passing to adapter according to that boolean value or any other criteria inside respective clicklisteners of ur buttons. Its quite simple and intuitive.

Or just share ur code i can do it for you. I really want points ))

Comment: Hi @Rinat, my object doesn't have boolean but it have field status [0-5] represents 6 status of transactions. 3 of them belong to each tab (image attachment). But still I have implemented Filterable interface like you mention. I posted my snippet below, if you have any suggestion please let me know.

Comment: it looks fine to me. It was easy wasn't it? Just you could have used constant final string instead of "u" to make code more understandable. Besides that its fine because when i used the same method for a serious app my senior mentor didnt have any issue .

Comment: I know i wasn't verbose while answering  but if it helped, could you accept the answer? Only if it helped you ofc.

Answer (score 1):

The job of an RecyclerAdapter is to show the data you're passing to it.
Unfortunately you don't provide any code, so I assume that the buttons are outside your RecyclerView.

Place a method inside your RecyclerAdapater which you can call from outside. The `notifyDataSetChanged()` re-runs `onBindViewHolder()` with your new provided data.

```
public void updateList(List<YourObjectType> yourObjects) {
    this.yourObjects = yourObjects;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Hi algtra, you're right. Buttons are outside recyclerview. I used your snippet in my previous code. Now I implemented Filterable interface which simply solve my problem. I posted my new solution below. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by implement Filterable interface in adapter. onCreate in activity, after initial adapter to recyclerview, I added this:

```
adapter.getFilter().filter("u");
```

Here is my adapter code:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

            if (charSequence.equals("u")) {
                List<Transaction> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Transaction trans : allTrans) {
                    if (trans.getTr_stt().equalsIgnoreCase("0") ||
                            trans.getTr_stt().equalsIgnoreCase("2") ||
                            trans.getTr_stt().equalsIgnoreCase("5")) {
                        filteredList.add(trans);
                    }
                }

                filteredTrans = filteredList;
            } else {
                List<Transaction> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Transaction trans : allTrans) {
                    if (trans.getTr_stt().equalsIgnoreCase("1") ||
                            trans.getTr_stt().equalsIgnoreCase("3") ||
                            trans.getTr_stt().equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {
                        filteredList.add(trans);
                    }
                }

                filteredTrans = filteredList;
            }


            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = filteredTrans;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            filteredTrans = (ArrayList<Transaction>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```